# Amazon Personalize- Domain Recommender Filter not Working

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-personalize

I have created an E-commerce recommender and successfully getting recommendations from it for frequently-bought-together use case. I just want to make sure that no "delisted" items would be included in the recommendations generated. So I added the attribute "DELISTED" in the schema for items-metadata such that the schema looks as follows:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Items",
    "namespace": "com.amazonaws.personalize.schema",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "ITEM_ID",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "PRICE",
            "type": "float"
        },
        {
            "name": "CATEGORY_L1",
            "type": "string",
            "categorical": true
        },
        {
            "name": "CATEGORY_L2",
            "type": "string",
            "categorical": true
        },
        {
            "name": "CATEGORY_L3",
            "type": "string",
            "categorical": true
        },
        {
            "name": "DESCRIPTION",
            "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
            ],
            "textual": true
        },
        {
            "name": "DELISTED",
            "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
            ],
            "categorical": true
        }
    ],
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

I re-uploaded the data and then  created a filter named "exclude-delisted" with the following expression:

```
EXCLUDE ItemID WHERE Items.DELISTED IN ("True")
```

and I finally use it in my get_recommendations calls as follows:

```
    get_recommendations_response = personalize_runtime.get_recommendations(
        recommenderArn="recommenderArn",
        filterArn = "arn:filter/exclude-delisted",
        itemId=item_id,
        numResults=20
    )
```

yet when checking the results I still observe that the recommendations returned include some items where delisted value is True. Any clue what could be going wrong here?

Comment: The process and approach you're using look fine. When filtering on item or user metadata fields, it can take up to 20 minutes before the filter(s) reflect data changes from an import or PutItems/PutUsers APIs. So be sure you wait after a data change. Also, you may want to verify the data in the dataset is represented as expected by exporting the dataset and inspecting (just to be sure).